# Why do some linux system calls include a C wrapper prototype even though glibc doesn't have them implemented?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

Take a look at `init_module` as an example:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/init_module.2.html

Page includes this function prototype:

```
int init_module(void *module_image, unsigned long len,
                       const char *param_values);
```

But then it says:

> Note: There are no glibc wrappers for these system calls; see
> NOTES.

So then why is there a function prototype here? who developed it?

Comment: Did you read [the NOTES section](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/init_module.2.html#NOTES)?

Comment: yes but don't understand it. is it saying before glibc versions 2.23 this was implanted but now it is not? so if I'm using the older version this header will work fine?

Comment: Then my question becomes: Why do you need to use this function? What problem is it supposed to solve for you? Right now your question is too much of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Honesty i'm not trying to use any of them. I'm trying to figure where are these prototypes coming from? are they libc implementations? or sort of a `standard` prototype provided by linux for libraries to follow? i.e if libc doesn't have then then why is a prototype listed here, it's just confusing.

Comment: Like *all* system calls, these have a specified interface (the "prototype" or "declaration" if you want). This interface is specified by the Linux kernel.

Comment: but an actually system call procedure is done in assembly not in C, i.e put a hex value in a register and then interrupt. If linux has specified these headers then why doesn't it just implement the whole thing in C? why does it leave the work to libc?

Comment: But you can't "call" a system function like another C function, because there exists no C functions other than what libc implements. It's libc which does the "assembly" thing for you, providing a suitable C interface for the low-level system call interface .Of course you can do this yourself, but it's a lot of work. Not to mention that the Linux system calls doesn't actually work exactly as the POSIX system calls are specified, for one thing the return a negative error code which libc have to translate into a failure/success return value, and its the libc which sets `errno` in case of failure.

Comment: I understand that thanks, but the question still remains, the prototypes are defined by linux as a `standard` and implanted by libc? or both defined and implanted by libc? if the former then why doesn't linux just implement it too?

Comment: The prototypes are declared by Linux because it is the kernel-userspace API. The C library implements the C API, which on Linux depends on the API provided by the kernel to implement the system specific stuff.

Comment: Got it, it would have made sense if linux just implemented them as well.

Comment: You have to separate the Linux *kernel* which defines the API and implements the system call interface, and the Linux *operating system* which is the kernel and all user-space applications and libraries (including the actuall callable POSIX API functions).  Perhaps Stallman was right with his insistence on the GNU/Linux moniker for the operating system, to separate it from the Linux kernel.